# Why do I get a strange byte sequence using UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: java

```
byte[] byt = "君".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (byte b : byt) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
}
```

Output:

```
11111111111111111111111111100101
11111111111111111111111110010000
11111111111111111111111110011011
```

This is right.

But:

```
byte[] byt = "君".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
for (byte b : byt) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
}
```

Output:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
11111111111111111111111111111111
1010100
11011
```

君's hexadecimal code is  `101010000011011`

So:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

What is this?

Answer (score 3):

The first to bytes `0xFEFF` or

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

are Byte Order Mark - they tell if the rest is encoded using Big Endian or Little Endian.

If you don't wan't them you can set the encoding explicitly - use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE` or `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE`